# How Can I set UIWebview or UIWindow in Landscape Mode in Global function?

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, landscape, uiwindow

I cannot use viewcontroller because viewcontroller crushed to unity(Game engine's name)'s application somehow. I needed to make my objective-c view in landscape to match unity's display.

I have searched on internet but what I found is force setting in controller.
So I want set UIWebView or UIWindow in Landscape mode for iphone inside global function.
How Can I set the code for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a `UIView` or `UIWindow` in landscape mode is simply a matter of drawing the view in landscape orientation.

What view controllers add is simply the possibility of handling the rotation in a specific way (allowing it or preventing it), but the end responsibility to draw in landscape/portrait is with your view.

As a concrete suggestion, you can try and use a `CGAffineTransformation` to rotate your view, if it makes things easier for you:

```
    CGAffineTransform newTransform;
    newTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
    view.transform = newTransform;
```

but without further hints as to how your view is made up, I cannot help more.

Comment: the way that I made view is simple. my view is UIWebView. [window addsubView:webView]; (webView = UIWebView) all of this setting is not in controller but in the global function. I will test your code when I am in office since I do not have Mac. Thank you very much for your kindness. I will try on your way